# Looking for an "introduction to photogrammetry" book with a well documented chapter on UAV

Tags: references, photogrammetry

I would like to recommend a book for my students to learn the basis of photogrammetry. I've read "Introduction to modern photogrammetry", 2001, from Mikhaïl, Bethel and McGlone. Unfortunately, the field has evolved a lot since 2001. I've found only a few other books on the net, but I would really like to have a chapter including UAV photogrammetry (and if possible also LiDAR, but this is secondary).

Is there a photogrammetry textbook with a good chapter on UAV's ?

EDIT: my students are either following a master in Environmental sciences or professionals from different domains who want to learn more about GIS.

Comment: Could you add some description of what you've already looked at and your thoughts on those?

Comment: For this Question to not be too broad in my view, I think the invitation for introduction books to be included alongside those related to your particular topic of interest should be edited out and the title narrowed accordingly.

Comment: @PolyGeo: I've removed the introduction books

Comment: @BradHards: I've read a few introduction books, but I could only find very small chapters UAV data processing in those. I will add a list tomorrow.

Comment: I've tried to rewrite my question in order to account for the arguments against the so called "shopping list questions". I could hardly make it more focused, and I don't think that it will attract spams or to many answers.

Comment: I've also looked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/what-in-depth-spatial-database-systems-tutorials-exist/44725#44725, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-are-some-free-and-open-source-gis-desktop-packages/89#89, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78700/what-is-a-good-resource-for-learning-to-hand-draw-a-map/78718#78718 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36736/what-is-the-best-open-source-software-package-for-remote-sensing/36740#36740 to understand why they were accepted but not mine.

Comment: I can only speak to the Q&A that you deemed me to be accepting of and note that I answered it 3.5 years ago when I had been participating in SO/SE sites for less than a month.  Now I would, and may well still, unhesitatingly propose closure for all four of those Questions.

Comment: I agree that this Question is now more focussed and would have withdrawn my close (as too broad) vote if I could see links to pages, a question mark in body and title, and generally just a but more expansion about what you have looked at and what you see as their shortcomings.  Googling "photogrammetry uav introduction" certainly produces some hits.

Comment: @radouxju - great question. only starting to learn about photogrammetry for meteorological purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full Credit to Henri Eisenbeiß (Author)

from the dissertation

**1.1.1
UAV photogrammetry**

**Extract:**
*"The new terminology UAV photogrammetry
describes aphotogrammetric measurement platform, which operates remotely controlled, semi-autonomously, or autonomously, without a pilot sitting in the vehicle. The platform is equipped with a photogrammetric measurement system, including, but not limited to a smallor medium size still video or video camera, thermal or infrared camera systems, airborne LiDAR system, or a combination thereof. Current standard UAVs allow the registration and tracking of the position and orientation of the implemented sensors in a local or global coordinate system. Hence, UAV photogrammetry can be understood as a new photogrammetric measurement tool. UAV photogrammetry opens various new applications in the close range domain, combining aerial and terrestrial photogrammetry, but also introduces new (near real time application and low cost alternatives to the classical manned aerial photogrammtery...*

Read Further [PDF]
http://www.igp-data.ethz.ch/berichte/Blaue_Berichte_PDF/105.pdf

Answer (score 3):

In Austria and Germany Karl Kraus taught remote sensing and photogrammetry and wrote several books which are IMO fundamental and very good for the understanding of this matter, despite the age of these books. Unfortunally he died in 2006. There is a translation made by Ian Harley and Stephen Kyle.

Karl Kraus, Photogrammetry, Volume 1, 2007:
Geometry from Images and Laser Scans, 2nd edition, Walter de Gruyter/Berlin, ISBN 978-3-11-019007-6;

Here are some examples from the WEB:

- **[Plotting Instruments and Stereoprocessing Procedures](http://books.google.de/books?id=sjP-IvYCYkQC&pg=PA286&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)**
- **[Photogrammetric Triangulation](http://books.google.de/books?id=sjP-IvYCYkQC&pg=PA246&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)**

Answer (score 1):

small format aerial photography is another option.

http://www.amazon.ca/Small-Format-Aerial-Photography-Principles-applications/dp/0444532609

it is a great book with several different approaches to collecting small format high resolution imagery (kites, balloons, uav etc).

they also have chapters on workflows, types of error, and case studies.

lots of good references to academic papers as well.

Comment: Thank you. It you be perfect if you could add more details about the key features.